# Button.PerformClick() doesn't fire Click event if the button is not visible in Android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I want my `btnAppShare` button to be clicked even if the button is invisible, I have written this code after button 1 click listener which is visible. Basically, I want that after completely executing `setOnClickListener` event of button1 my button2 gets automatically clicked and perform its `setOnClickListener.

```
 btnAppShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppShare);
    btnAppShare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnAppShare.performClick();
    btnAppShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("regId", regId);

                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And it's correct behaviour for `Button#performClick()`

Comment: @3mpty Then is there any work around to execute setOnClickListener of invisible button

Comment: Put everything inside `onClick()` in another method, and call that method from `onClick()`, and wherever you're trying to call `performClick()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it just make more sense to write external methods for these? Such that the onClick method for button 1 just calls a method like "method1()", while the onClick method for button 2 calls two methods "method2()" and "method1()"?

Comment: In my case ,moving setOnClickListener() above performClick worked. :)

Answer (score 9):

Use `View#callOnClick()`:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
//set here listener
b.callOnClick();
```

Unlike `performClick()` it calls onClickListener method directly, without view related stuff. Button has to have listener BEFORE you call click action!

Answer (score 1):

Make a method and call that after setting the button invisble, then inside the `onClick` method of the listener, call that same method.

```
btnAppShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppShare);
btnAppShare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
myMethod();
btnAppShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
        myMethod();
    }
});

public void myMethod()
{
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("regId", regId);

        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click something that is not visible but what you can do is make that button background transparent with this attribute in its xml

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

this way button will not be visible but clickable.

Hope it helps

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you'd also have to change the text color. This seems messy because the user could still click the button, whereas what he wants seems to be one button does function X while the other does functions Y then X

Comment: @jace you got a point but I didn't cover it because if hes setting the button already invisible then it means buttons got no text for the user to read, user already is not reading anything from button so button should not have any text anyway

Answer (score -1):

if you want to

```
view.performClick()
```

something like that, you should write your setOnclick method upper the performclick  method. Because codes flow up to down and button should generate setOnclick method before calling.